# Is this design good for bill generation android app?

Tags: mobile

[image: Bill]

This would be a scroll view for bill generation and marking the bill is paid on server via paid button. Can this be improved ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: the image was high resolution. now the details are not visible after edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks ok to me, considering its a very focused task of generating bills quickly over the counter. However few suggestions:

1) Assuming the "How Many" section has numbers - like 1, 2, 3, 4..10. Each when tapped means the quantity. How about tackling a case of above 10? Or is this out of context? Something to think about.

2) You could add a recent orders, or recent items section - which essentially could be an easy way to get hold of the fast moving items.

3) Paid button could say - "Paid - Generate bill" or something, to give more context.

4) Again, its about context - but how do you handle multiple items?

Comment: I changed design little to add multiple items